# Creating an instance of a class in another class

Tags: c#, oop, namespaces

I am trying to make a Node inside the `LL` class which are two different `.cs` files

LL.cs

```
using System;
using Node;

namespace LinkedList{

    class LL{
        private Node head{get; set;}

        public static void Main(){


        }

    }
}
```

Node.cs

```
using System;
namespace Node
{

public class Node{
        private int data{get; set;}
        private Node next{get; set;}

    }
}
```

Why would I be getting these errors:

> LL.cs(2,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Node' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

And:

> LL.cs(7,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Node' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

If I used the `using Node` directive to indicate the namespace.

Thanks.

EDIT:
An obvious solution is to put both the classes in the same .cs file like so

```
using System;

namespace LinkedList{
  //using global::Node;

   public class Node{
     private int data { get; set; }
     private Node next { get; set; }
   }

  class LL{

    private Node head { get; set; }



    public static void Main(){

    }
 }
}
```

But this is considered bad practice and this will cause future issues so I am trying to solve the main issue so that it won't reappear in future projects.

Comment: this should work - how are you compiling?

Comment: You have same namespace as class name. Change the namespace from 'Node' to something else.

Comment: The error I see when I tried this code as-is says, *Node is a namespace but is used as a type*. I would highly recommend not using `Node` as both the namespace and the type to avoid confusion. Or use `private Node.Node ...`. But if it were me, I'd change the name.

Comment: You should probably also have both classes in the same namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Please change the namespace name to other than class name. The program should compile successfully.

Comment: Just changed the namespace for Node to "aa" and got a similar error  
                                                                                              
 LL.cs(2,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'aa' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
LL.cs(7,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Node' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it's working.

Node.cs

```
using System;

namespace Node
{
   public class Node
   {
     private int data { get; set; }
     private Node next { get; set; }
   }
}
```

LL.cs

```
using System;

namespace LinkedList
{
  using global::Node;

  class LL
  {
    private Node head { get; set; }

    public static void Main()
    {

    }
 }
}
```

Comment: this does not work still the  same error error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Node' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Daytona211 
You can also try this if you are still getting errors.
   use  
    `using global::Node` 
instead of 
    `using Node = Node.Node`

Also edited original answer

Comment: Still the same error. I'm starting to think it's the compiler